# Improper answer count in the question page

Tags: bug

[image]

For some of the questions, the SE does not say answers exists.It will just say "votes" but no "answers". But if you open the question, it will show many answers.

What would be the reason?

e.g. [Java Thread Synchronized object for wait and notify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981759/java-thread-synchronized-object-for-wait-and-notify/31990627?s=18|0.0000#31990627) is shown as "0" votes now in main page. If you open this question, you can find multiple answers for this question

Comment: For example? Screenshots or it didn't happen.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of what you actually mean?

Comment: Caching, basically.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: Generally I would like to select 0 answer questions to provide answer.But it is showing that question has been answered X minutes ago with no answer count below votes.

Comment: add `is:question` to your search criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the "A:" in front of the title? That means you're looking at an answer.

[image]

Answers can't have answers, therefore they don't have an answer *count.* In the search results, answers will say "answered x ago" and questions will say "asked x ago", both referring to when the post was created.

Notice how the "example" you link to takes you straight to an answer. I assume you opened the page from search and copied the URL over here. The search result was an answer, and that answer has a score of 0.

You mentioned in the comments:

> Generally I would like to select 0 answer questions to provide answer.But it is showing that question has been answered X minutes ago with no answer count below votes.

To get questions with zero answers, you need to add `is:q answers:0` to your search. This will ensure you get only questions, and those questions will have 0 answers. You may want to refine this a little by also adding `closed:0 locked:0` to the search, so you won't get questions you can't answer do to closing or locking. See the [help page on searching](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for other modifiers you could use.